# ¿Como puedo pasar este ejercicio a bucles for o while

Tags: java

¿Como podría transformar este ejercicio sólo a bucles for o while?
Gracias. Les dejo el código abajo.

Enunciado:

Crea un programa que "dibuje" un cuadrado formado por cifras
sucesivas, con el tamaño que indique el usuario, hasta un
máximo de 9. Por ejemplo, si desea tamaño 5, el cuadrado sería
así:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
```

Código:

```
package entrega3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Entrega3 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Inicialización de variables
 int num = 0;
 String cuadrado = "";
 Scanner scanNum = new Scanner(System.in);

 //Solución
 System.out.print("Introduce un número entre 0 y 9: ");
 num = scanNum.nextInt();
 while(num>9 || num<0){
 if(num>9){
 System.out.print("Introduce un número menor que 9, por favor: ");
 num = scanNum.nextInt();
 }else{
 System.out.print("Introduce un número mayor que 0, por favor: ");
 num = scanNum.nextInt();
 }
 }
 switch(num){
 case 1: System.out.println("1");
 break;
 case 2: System.out.println("11");
 System.out.println("22");
 break;
 case 3: System.out.println("111");
 System.out.println("222");
 System.out.println("333");
 break;
 case 4: System.out.println("1111");
 System.out.println("2222");
 System.out.println("3333");
 System.out.println("4444");
 break;
 case 5: System.out.println("11111");
 System.out.println("22222");
 System.out.println("33333");
 System.out.println("44444");
 System.out.println("55555");
 break;
 case 6: System.out.println("111111");
 System.out.println("222222");
 System.out.println("333333");
 System.out.println("444444");
 System.out.println("555555");
 System.out.println("666666");
 break;
 case 7: System.out.println("1111111");
 System.out.println("2222222");
 System.out.println("3333333");
 System.out.println("4444444");
 System.out.println("5555555");
 System.out.println("6666666");
 System.out.println("7777777");
 break;
 case 8: System.out.println("11111111");
 System.out.println("22222222");
 System.out.println("33333333");
 System.out.println("44444444");
 System.out.println("55555555");
 System.out.println("66666666");
 System.out.println("77777777");
 System.out.println("88888888");
 break;
 case 9: System.out.println("111111111");
 System.out.println("222222222");
 System.out.println("333333333");
 System.out.println("444444444");
 System.out.println("555555555");
 System.out.println("666666666");
 System.out.println("777777777");
 System.out.println("888888888");
 System.out.println("999999999");
 break;
 default:System.out.println("Introduce un valor numérico");
 break;
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: Has intentado algo con los ciclos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es en base al número ingresado iterar la cantidad de veces y obtener el valor, en mi caso use `i = 1` y en cada iteración va a incrementar su valor. Como ya tenemos el valor principal ahora debes con la ayuda de otro bucle for concatenar el valor i `n - 1` veces. Una vez finalizado el for imprime el valor y vuelve la cadena a la normalidad para el siguiente número.

```
String cadena = "";
String valor = "";
num = scanNum.nextInt();
for (int i  = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    valor = Integer.toString(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++){
        cadena += valor;    
    }
    System.out.println(cadena);  
    cadena = "";
}
```

Te aconsejo que revises [documentación de ciclos y practiques](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/Sentencia_for)

Comment: Resuelto, me ha servido bastante. Muchas gracias. Saludos

Comment: @josemanuel si te ha servido considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pulsando el check bajo la puntuacion . Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

```
num = scanNum.nextInt();
for(int z=0;z<num;z++){
  for(int i=1; i<num;i++){
      if(i==num){
         System.out.println(Integer.toString(i));
      }else{
         System.out.print(Integer.toString(i));
      }
  }
}
```

Lo que hace este fragmento de código es hacer dos fors. El primero será el que hará que se printeen la cantidad de líneas que ha solicitado el usuario. El segundo se encargará de printear estas líneas con un número que irá creciendo en función de el índice del for. 
Los dos fors irán desde 1 (primer número a sacar por pantalla) hasta el número que ha escrito el usuario.
 Al estar un for dentro del otro se conseguirá que quede en forma cuadrada.
 Dentro del for que hace que se printeen los números cuando el índice sea igual que el número dicho por el usuario hará System.out.println() para que salte de línea. En cambio si este no es igual al índice no saltará a la siguiente línea para que quede en forma de cuadrado.

Comment: Por favor edita tu respuesta y aclara como es que este fragmento resuelve el problema planteado.

Comment: Gracias por avisar, ya he editado el código aclarandolo, no había pensado en hacerlo previamente. Saludos